# How to optimize Postgresql max_connections and node-postgres connection pool?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-rds, node-postgres

In brief, I am having trouble supporting more than 5000 read requests per minute from a data API leveraging Postgresql, Node.js, and node-postgres. The bottleneck appears to be in between the API and the DB. Here are the implmentation details.

I'm using an AWS Postgresql RDS database instance (m4.4xlarge - 64 GB mem, 16 vCPUs, 350 GB SSD, no provisioned IOPS) for a Node.js powered data API.  By default the RDS's max_connections=5000.  The node API is load-balanced across two clusters with 4 processes each (2 Ec2s with 4 vCPUs running the API with PM2 in cluster-mode).  I use [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) to bind the API to the Postgresql RDS, and am attempting to use it's connection pooling feature.  Below is a sample of my connection pool code:

```
var pool = new Pool({
    user: settings.database.username,
    password: settings.database.password,
    host: settings.database.readServer,
    database: settings.database.database,
    max: 25, 
    idleTimeoutMillis: 1000
});

/* Example of pool usage */
pool.query('SELECT my_column FROM my_table', function(err, result){
    
    /* Callback code here */
});
```

Using this implementation and testing with a load tester, I can support about 5000 requests over the course of one minute, with an average response time of about 190ms (which is what I expect).  As soon as I fire off more than 5000 requests per minute, my response time increases to over 1200ms in the best of cases and in the worst of cases the API begins to frequently timeout. Monitoring indicates that for the EC2s running the Node.js API, CPU utilization remains below 10%. Thus my focus is on the DB and the API's binding to the DB.

I have attempted to increase (and decrease for that matter) the node-postgres "max" connections setting, but there was no change in the API response/timeout behavior. I've also tried provisioned IOPS on the RDS, but no improvement. Also, interestingly, I scaled the RDS up to m4.10xlarge (160 GB mem, 40 vCPUs), and while the RDS CPU utilization dropped greatly, the overall performance of the API worsed considerably (couldn't even support the 5000 requests per minute that I was able to with the smaller RDS).

I'm in unfamilar territory in many respects and am unsure of how to best determine which of these moving parts is bottlenecking API performance when over 5000 requests per minute. As noted I have attempted a variety of adjustments based on the review of Postgresql configuration documentation and node-postgres documentation, but to no avail.

If anyone has advice on how to diagnose or optimize I would greatly appreciate it.

#### UPDATE

***After scaling up to m4.10xlarge, i performed a series of load-tests, varying the number of request/min and the max number of connections in each pool.  Here are some screen captures of monitoring metrics:***

[image: monitoring metrics]

[image: db connections]

Comment: max connection default is 100. Have you tried increasing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to support more then 5k requests, while maintaining the same response rate, you'll need better hardware...

The simple math states that:
`5000 requests*190ms avg = 950k ms divided into 16 cores ~ 60k ms per core` 
 which basically means your system was highly loaded.
(I'm guessing you had some spare CPU as some time was lost on networking)

Now, the really interesting part in your question comes from the scale up attempt: m4.10xlarge (160 GB mem, 40 vCPUs).
The drop in CPU utilization indicates that the scale up freed DB time resources - So you need to push more requests!
2 suggestions:

- Try increasing the connection pool to `max: 70` and look at the network traffic (depending on the amount of data you might be hogging the network)
- also, are your requests to the DB a-sync from the application side? make sure your app can actually push more requests.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try adjusting "max" to 70, (with the Node.js API replicated 8 times in the cluster, that means an effective max of 70*8 = 560).  With respect to async DB requests from the application -  I have assumed everything is async, given the async features of Node.js and the [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) Postgres client being described as "non-blocking" by its developer.  But I have to admit that I haven't scrutinized the libraries internals to confirm that.

Comment: Do you have monitoring on the db server? Io/network - did anything spike?  And just wondering if increasing it took you down to 2k - does reducing it to 10 improve stuff?

Comment: Here  r details from the 10xlarge test with `max: 20`:  load test of 3000 read queries/min. CPU is about 7%.  No timeouts;  load test with 4000 read querie/minute. CPU is about 64%. More than half of the application requests timeout. I'll try to some monitoring screen grabs and update the post.

Comment: We know cpu isn't the bottleneck- look at io and network. No timeouts means you can push more :)

Comment: As per your advice I performed a series of load tests on the m4.10xlarge.  I've updated the original question with what appear to be the most responsive DB metrics.

Comment: Hi, something in you app configuration isn't working - both for max=10 and max=70 you only have 80 db connections. Btw, how was you app cpu during the tests - does the 8 vcpus handle all the requests?

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to make use of a separate `Pool` for each API call, based on the call's priority:

```
const highPriority = new Pool({max: 20}); // for high-priority API calls
const lowPriority = new Pool({max: 5}); // for low-priority API calls
```

Then you just use the right pool for each of the API calls, for optimum service/connection availability.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in read performance can set up replication between two (or more) PostgreSQL instances, and then use [pgpool II](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page) to load balance between the instances.

Scaling horizontally means you won't start hitting the max instance sizes at AWS if you decide next week you need to go to 10,000 concurrent reads.

You also start to get some HA in your architecture.

--

Many times people will use [pgbouncer](https://pgbouncer.github.io/) as a connection pooler even if they have one built into their application code already.  pgbouncer works really well and is typically easier to configure and manage that pgpool, but it doesn't do load balancing.  I'm not sure if it would help you very much in this scenario though.

Comment: I have definitely considered read-replicas, but am interested in know more about replication lag.  Our application has users that write data very often, which is then leveraged in a way the affects the content of their read-request payloads.  Thus, replication lag could introduce other latencies into our solution.  Is there a way to estimate replication lag?

Comment: There is a discussion about replication lag measurement on one of the postgresql lists here:  https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CADKbJJWz9M0swPT3oqe8f9+tfD4-F54uE6Xtkh4nERpVsQnjnw@mail.gmail.com

Comment: In my experience, it usually isn't too bad.  By the time the page renders and the end user makes a query, replication is caught up.  Where you run into issues is when you send a write immediately followed by a read.  I think there are some settings in pgpool that help in those scenarios, although it has been several years since I messed with pgpool setttings.